# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncListener

Tags: spring-mvc

i m having the some exception while running spring application i dont know why its happen please help me out  i have imported the application in my system  and try to run but it shows this error please help me figure it out

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

this is web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>EmployeeWebSpring</display-name>


    <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for 
        handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ds</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ds</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

this is ds-servlet.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName" />
        <property value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee"
            name="url" />
        <property value="hr" name="username" />
        <property value="hr123" name="password" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="departmentDaoImpl"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.DepartmentDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectDaoImpl" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.ProjectDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeserviceImpl" class=" com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl">
        <property name="daoImpl" ref="employeeDaoImpl" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="departmentserviceImpl"
        class=" com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl">
        <property name="departmentDAOImpl" ref="departmentDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="projectserviceImpl" class=" com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl">
        <property name="projectDAOImpl" ref="projectDaoImpl" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="mycontroller"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.SearchEmployeeController">
        <property name="employeeServiceImpl" ref="employeserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="emplController" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.EmployeeController">
        <property name="employeeServiceImpl" ref="employeserviceImpl" />
        <property name="projectServiceImpl" ref="projectserviceImpl" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="deaprtmentController" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.DepartmentController">
        <property name="departmentServiceImpl" ref="departmentserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="deptCotrooler"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.SearchDepartmentController">
        <property name="departmentServiceImpl" ref="departmentserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectController" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.ProjectController">
        <property name="projectServiceImpl" ref="projectserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectSearchController"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers.SearchProjectController">
        <property name="projectServiceImpl" ref="projectserviceImpl"></property>
    </bean>




    <bean id="configurationLoader"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader" />
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator"
        p:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="com/nousinfo/resources/messages" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>








    <!-- configuring BeanNameViewResolver -->
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"></bean> 
        configuring exception Resolver <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"> 
        <property name="exceptionMappings"> <props> <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DAOException">dberrorView</prop> 
        <prop key="java.lang.NumberFormatException">notANumber</prop> </props> </property> 
        </bean> configuring views required to render the view for /search.spring 
        <bean name="successSingleEmp" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"> 
        <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/EmployeeDetail.jsp" /> </bean> <bean 
        name="successMultipleEmps" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"> 
        <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/EmployeeList.jsp" /> </bean> <bean name="dberrorView" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"> <property name="url" 
        value="/WEB-INF/DBError.jsp" /> </bean> <bean name="notANumber" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"> 
        <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/NotANumberError.jsp" /> </bean> CONFIGURING 
        THE MEASSAGE RESOURCES FOR THIS APPLICTION CONTEXT <bean id="messageSource" 
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
        <property name="basename" value="/com/nousinfo/resources/ApplicationResources" 
        /> </bean> -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `2.5` servlet spec, while [AsyncListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncListener.html) comes with `3.0` servlets.

Comment: how to remove this with existing configuration

Comment: Make sure your servlet container supports 3.0 spec ([link](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for Tomcat, Jetty 8 and 9). Then use 3.0 version in web.xml: xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd", version="3.0". If you use maven, look at dependencies too.