# HOWTO use jetty-servlets' GZipFilter in Tomcat webapp

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jetty, servlet-filters

I am trying to use the [GZipFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/GzipFilter.html) servlet provided in the [`jetty-servlets`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Servlets_Bundled_with_Jetty) lib. My web app runs on [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org) rather than Jetty. I know that Jetty is another servlet engine, but I should be able to use individual components.

I use `maven` to build my application. Whenever I include `jetty-servlets` in my pom, my web application refuses to start, failing at the declaration of `GzipFilter` in the `web.xml`.

The error is as follows,

`Mar 31, 2014 3:03:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter GzipFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)`

I knew that Jetty-Servlets has a dependency on servlets-api, so I excluded it from the dependency in maven.

My snippet of `pom.xml` looks like,

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`

My snippet of `web.xml` looks like,

`<filter>
      <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>`

Comment: What happens when you don't list that `exclusion`? Whenever I've built servlets with Maven I've used the `<scope>provided</scope>` option for `servlet-api`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979957/maven-dependency-for-servlet-3-0-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846673/tomcat-servlet-api-jar-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing `javax.servlet.AsyncListener` class is part of [Servlet Spec 3.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncListener.html), which makes sense because [Jetty 9.0.x follows that spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)#History).
Perhaps you are using an older version of Tomcat? Tomcat versions [prior to 7.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) do not implement this, in which case you have a problem.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406990/noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-asynclistener).

Comment: Oh, ok. I am indeed using Tomcat 6.0. So is there no way I can use jetty-servlets in tomcat 6?

Comment: You might be able to use an older version of Jetty such as 7.x. I have never tried it though. The error that you reported should go away, but you mind encounter another.